# input() Function Not giving request

Tags: python, input, user-input

I am learning python through a book named, "Python Crash Course 2nd Edition" made by, "Eric Matthes", which told me to download an IDE called Sublime Text. I am currently learning the, "input()" function and I can't get a request for input, is the problem with the IDE or with my code?
Code:

```
inp = input("Please give input: ")

print(f"This is the input: {inp}")
```

I did notice that the output allowed the user to edit what had been printed, could this make the input not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime text doesn't support input in the console. I suggest You installing other IDE like PyCharm from Jetbrains, it's very good and there is the free version.

Comment: thanks for the help, will do.